# How To Correctly Bind Form in Vue & Vuex - Difference of v-model, :value & :value.sync

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm fairly new to Vue & Vuex and am unsure on how to set up my form correctly.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-if="error">{{error.message}}</div>
        <form @submit.prevent>
            <h1>Register</h1>
            <input type="email" name="" id="" :value.sync="email" placeholder="Email">
            <input type="password" :value.sync="password" placeholder="Password">
            <button @click="signup">Submit</button>
            <a href="login">Sign in</a>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import {fireAuth} from '~/plugins/firebase.js'
export default {
  data: () => ({
    email: '',
    password: '',
    error: ''
  }),
  methods: {
    signup() {
      fireAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password).then(res => {
        if (res) {
          this.$store.commit('setCurrentUser', res.user)
          this.$router.push('/')
        }
      }).catch(err => {
        this.error = err
        console.log(err)
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

At first I tried v-model to bind the form, it was throwing and error as I was mutating the store but I'm not storing email and password so I'm unsure how this is mutating the store? If I use `:value` or `:value.sync` then the email and password fields remain an empty string, so I'm not sure how to set up these correctly or how they differ from v-model

Edit: Adding my code from the store as requested

```
export const state = () => ({
    currentUser: {}
})

export const mutations = {
    setCurrentUser (state, obj) {
    state.currentUser = obj
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your store? v-model="email" and v-model="password will bind it to the component state (the data object) that wont throw an error. I am guessing when you pass res.user to setCurrentUser is where your trouble can be found. Post the code to the store and we can go from there.

Comment: Thanks, I have just updated it for you

Comment: Just to make sure, are you trying to sync between the inputs to the store?

Comment: No, I only need to use the values of the inputs so I can send to firebase, I'll then be using what firebase to commit to the store. I think the way I have explained it badly has highlighted my own lack of understanding on this and think I may be overcomplicating what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false
Vue.config.productionTip = false

const vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data() {
        return {
            email: '',
            password: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        signup() {
            console.log(this.email) // email value
            console.log(this.password) // password value
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="app">
         <div>
            <form @submit.prevent="signup">
               <h1>Register</h1>
               <input type="email" v-model="email" placeholder="Email">
               <input type="password" v-model="password" placeholder="Password">
               <input type="submit">
            </form>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure if I understand how that helps, I'm not trying to store the value's from the form, so I won't need to commit them to the store. So as the data is only needed in this page, I have tried to only handle the email and password here. Unless my understanding of the purpose of data is wrong?

Comment: Sorry i don't understood, post updated, `v-model` works fine

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the solution, it was the way in which I was trying to use firebase. I have used v-model, but am using a firebase method `onAuthStateChanged`, only if that is called will I change the store. So in my firebase.js I added

```
const fireAuth = firebase.auth()
const fireDb = firebase.database()
export { fireAuth, fireDb }

export default async ({ store }) => {
    await asyncOnAuthStateChanged(store)
}

function asyncOnAuthStateChanged (store) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        fireAuth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            resolve(user)
            store.commit('setCurrentUser', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user)))
        })
    })
}
```